# RPC fails when lunching msWord remotely on automation

Tags: delphi, ms-word, automation, iis-7.5, windows-server-2008-r2

I have an application that instantiates an object which launches a Word application and does some operations through a Word macro.
Everything works well when I launch it on the server but I get a remote procedure call fail when done remotely.

Here the code where it fails :

```
for i := 0 to myFiles.Count - 1 do
    //...
    if Uppercase(ExtractFileExt(myFiles.Items(i))) = '.DOC' then
            begin
               App_Word := CreateOleObject('Word.application');
               SendDebug('word lunched');
                //...
               SendDebug('macro done');
            finally
               SendDebug('word closing');
               if App_Word.Documents.Count>0 then
                   SendDebug('Another document :' + InttoSTr(App_Word.Documents.Count));
                   App_Word.Quit(EmptyParam, EmptyParam, EmptyParam);
                   App_Word := Unassigned;
               end;
             end
          Else
            if Uppercase(ExtractFileExt(Fichiers.Items(i))) = '.XLS' then
              //...
            End
            //...

          SendDebug('doc '+IntToStr(i+1)+' generated');
        end;
      SendDebug('docs generated');
    end;
```

Here the log file (SendDebug) when launched locally on the server:

```
word lunched
macro done
word closing
Another document :1
doc 1 generated
docs generated
```

and here when launched remotely:

```
word lunched
macro done
word closing
```

I think the problem happens when executing this command remotely:

```
App_Word.Documents.Count
```

because the tests are done using the exact same files.

I'm running this app on IIS W2008R2 with office2K. Can you please help me solve this issue ?

I got this error in the event log every time running the app remotely :

> Faulting application name: WINWORD.EXE, version: 9.0.0.6926, time
>   stamp: 0x3d97fbe5 Faulting module name: MSO9.DLL, version: 9.0.0.7616,
>   time stamp: 0x3e9f5ea2 Exception code: 0xc0000005 Fault offset:
>   0x00033ae3 Faulting process id: 0xdc8

Comment: Is the IIS process running as a service?

Comment: No, it's running as apppoolidentity but I don't think this is the problem because the user running iis is the same locally and remotely.